# How to detect Java string inside a .so file?

Tags: java, reverse-engineering, nasm, disassembly

I'm recompiling a Java program, and I have the following method:

```
public static native String getMyString(String s);
```

`getMyString` is implemented inside mylibrary.so, and looks like follows:

```
; Scrambler::getMyString(char  const*)
EXPORT _ZN9Scrambler18getMyStringEPKc
_ZN9Scrambler18getMyStringEPKc
LDR             R1, =(mystring - 0x14FC8)
PUSH            {R4-R6,LR}
ADD             R1, PC  ; "mystring"
MOV             R4, R0
BLX             strcasecmp
CMP             R0, #0
BNE.W           loc_150FC
```

which than ends up in

```
LDR             R5, =(unk_6AE24 - 0x14FD8)
ADD             R5, PC
```

The `R5` seems to be the return value here.

The `unk_6AE24` looks like follows:

```
                                              27
68 5D 6D 06 3F 10 6D 26  32 10 56 12 06 3F 32 5D
12 27 26 4B 0D 5D 27 4B  6E 0D 2B 06 32 5D 68 24
3F 32 06 24 70 56 00 63  69 4C 1D 06 5A 7F 0C 34
1E 67 3B 63 32 5F 16 1D  34 5F 1E 32 42 69 18 49
3F 51 49 0C 1F 0C 0E 77  2F 44 69 7F 5A 0C 0B 34
0C 34 1C 24 32 5F 7F 00  00 00 00 1D 30 3B 5F 30
```

IDA suggests, that the string in question is `27 68 5D 6D` or "'h]m", but I'm having my doubts. When I was using c++ ages ago, the strings used to end with 0, which would make for return value of `27 68 5D 6D 06 3F 10 6D 26  32 10 56 12 06 3F 32 5D 12 27 26 4B 0D 5D 27 4B  6E 0D 2B 06 32 5D 68 24 3F 32 06 24 70 56` . Or we could be talking about java string, which may have its own format.

What kind of string will `getMyString` return?

Comment: The producer of the library has gone out of their way to make it difficult to reverse-engineer. Is this something you really should be doing? i.e. is it even legal?

Comment: the producer of this library has asked me to check how secure it is. I don't think that it is secure at all, but I'd like to make a point by showing him the string

Comment: Fair point. You could use the `strings mylib.so | sort -u` on the file to extract all the strings quickly. The strings should be in UTF-8 format with a two byte length at the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What kind of string will getMyString return?

It will return a `java.lang.String`, you can get that from the declaration.

The actual character data will (probably) be one redirection away from that.  (a `String` is probably a pointer to a `char` array and a size).  Keep in mind that in Java, a `char` is 16 bits.

What are you trying to do, anyway?  Much easier to just set a breakpoint right after `getMyString` returns and look at the return value in a debugger.

Comment: so what kind of string format should I expect? I mean, byte-by-byte. I can't run the software.

Comment: on the other hand, I suppose, I can. Thanks!